# Removing the restriction for Windows's reserved file names

Tags: windows

Following words are reserved on Windows file system. Simply you cannot have files contain one of following words.

```
  CON, PRN, AUX, NUL 
  COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9
  LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9
```

Is it possible to remove these restrictions in Windows?

Comment: WHY?   These have been Windows names for several decades.

Comment: I'm editing Linux kernel code in Windows and for git especially aux.c and .h are being pain which affect the whole my process. We are in 2022 and those restrictions sound unnecessary anymore.

Comment: These names are very widely used, even today. I suggest a different approach as I do not believe you can remove these name reservations.

Comment: I just used COM4: on a Windows 11 machine to program a controller I have.

Comment: I use also many serial ports every day. What is the problem? See Win32 Device Namespaces section here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#win32-file-namespaces

Comment: I am not sure if there is a problem. But I do not believe you can use the names you listed for other purposes.

Comment: Thinking again:  You can probably use whatever names you wish so long as you do not create a conflict when you do this.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  You can create a file called **con1.txt**.  Sure you can't make **con.txt**.  But it's not clear what you mean.  Anyway, they are reserved for a reason.  Even if you were to find a way to create those file names, something else will not work.

Comment: @RohitGupta I gave an example in the comment, I need to have files aux.c and aux.h without any restriction.

Comment: I guess you didn't read any of the comments.  The names are reserved because the OS is written that way.  End of Story.  Even if you bypass it, it will bite you later.  If you want to be stubborn about file names, then the solution is, **don;t use windows**.

Comment: I don't need any of your useless comments nor assumptions. The question is clear. If you know the answer then please answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restriction seems alleviated by Windows 11.

It was not possible to have `aux.c` with Windows 10 but Windows 11 seems fully compatible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).